# Optional Routing in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to have optional dynamic routing in nextjs.
I have a  signup page what i want to have like optional query params like this /signup/:id
also i don't want to be shown when hover over the link.
When i use 'as' property in link it throws an error.

```
Error: The provided `as` value (/signup) is incompatible with the `href` value (/signup/[id]). Read more: https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/incompatible-href-as
```

[image: Pages]

[image]

Comment: `id` property must resolve to a value by the time the link is rendered.

Comment: You could setup a `/signup/index.js` page so that `/signup` would route to that instead. No need to mess around with the `as` property then.